# Migrate new model fields

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, database-migration

When I use `manage.py makemigrations <app>` only columns with relations are migrated to pg database.

How to instruct django to migrate new basic non-relational columns, like:

`title = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)`

I'm using django 1.8.2. on Ubuntu

Comment: What tries have you already done? you should provide some ideas and tries you've already done, or examples you've read...

Comment: I already mentioned what I have tried - if I add relational field (i.e. `field = models.ForeignKey(...)`) then `manage.py makemigrations <app>` updates the model table in my postgres database, but for non-relational fields I don't get update/migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No fields at all are being migrated when you run `manage.py makemigrations <app>`, as that command only creates a new migration in your `<app>/migrations/` directory. It's only when you run `manage.py migrate` that changes are written to the database.

If you are not getting the expected results, have a look at the newest migration and determine which fields it affects. All fields should be targeted by migrations, not relational fields only. Changing properties like `max_length`, `blank`, `required` etc. should trigger migrations. If they don't it's probably because your changes doesn't require any database schema modification.

If you are still having problems, please post:

1. Your models prior to model change
2. Your models after model change
3. The migration generated by `makemigrations`